# Foreman start and hide the web process output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, foreman, procfile

I'm using Foreman to run my Rails 4 application, and I'm getting duplicate output. Web shows pretty much the same info as Log.

Can I run foreman and just hide the Web output?

[image]

My procfile:

```
web: bundle exec passenger start -p $PORT --max-pool-size 3
log: tail -f ./log/development.log
```

Answer (score 7):

The entries in your Procfile are just commands to run and you can tinker with them the same way you would on the command line.

So you could redirect all of the stdout for your web process to `/dev/null` (looks like you might be on a *nix system):

```
web: bundle exec passenger start -p $PORT --max-pool-size 3 > /dev/null
```